# Wordpress users roles wp-admin

Tags: user-roles

A friend asked me to Review him wp page left unfinished by the company he contracted, I can't do a backup because on wp-admin page is no visible the settings although I am administrator, dos wp have super admins? How can I see them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In WordPress, there is no concept of "super admins" in the same way that there is in a multisite installation. However, there may be users with the "administrator" role who have access to all areas of the site, including the WordPress settings.

If you are an administrator and you are unable to access the WordPress settings, it could be due to a number of reasons. Here are a few things you could try:

- Check that you are logged in with an account that has the "administrator" role.
- Check if there are any plugins or themes that may be blocking access to the settings. You can try deactivating all plugins and switching to a default theme to see if this resolves the issue.
- Check if there are any errors in your site's `wp-config.php` file that may be preventing access to the settings.
- If you are using a caching plugin, try clearing the cache to see if that resolves the issue.

If none of these suggestions helps, you may need to access the site's database and check via your Host cpanel for any issues there. You can use a tool like `phpMyAdmin` to access the database `wp_users` table and check for any problems.

while on `PHPMyAdmin`, Check if there are any issues with the user roles: The user roles in WordPress determine what permissions users have on the site. If your user role has been changed or there are any issues with the user roles, it could prevent you from accessing the dashboard. You can check the `wp_usermeta` table to see if there are any issues with the user roles.

To change user roles in the wp_usermeta table in WordPress using phpMyAdmin, you can follow these steps:

1. Log in to your hosting account and open the phpMyAdmin tool.
2. Select the WordPress database from the list of databases on the left side of the page.
3. Click on the `wp_usermeta` table to open it.
4. Click on the "Browse" tab to view the contents of the table.
5. Find the row corresponding to the user whose role you want to change. The `user_id` column will contain the ID of the user, and the `meta_key` column will contain the string "`wp_capabilities`".
6. Click on the "Edit" link for the row you want to modify.
7. In the "meta_value" field, enter the desired role for the user. The role should be specified as a serialized array, with the key corresponding to the role and the value set to true. For example, to set the user's role to "administrator", you would enter the following value in the "meta_value" field: `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}`.

if a user has the "administrator" role, the `wp_capabilities` field for that user might contain the following value: `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}`. This value indicates that the user has the "administrator" role, with the key `s:13:"administrator"` corresponding to the role and the value `b:1;` indicating that the `role is enabled`.

8. Click the "Go" button to save the changes.

Please note that changing user roles in the database can have serious consequences if not done carefully. It is important to make sure you understand the implications of modifying the database before making any changes. If you are not comfortable working with databases, it is best to seek the help of a developer or database administrator.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: thanks you a lot for your detailed answer, I really apreciate that. have a good day

Answer (score 2):

See @Tamara answers below regarding edits in phpmyadmin for user role levels.

There is likely a plugin installed or a modification in the functions.php file that is removing items from the menu list.

Log into phpmyadmin for the site, check your username login against those of the other company. Likely the permission level is going to be different.

*[Removed instructions for wp_usermeta as it is no longer relevant]*

Most likely there is a plugin or edit in the functions.php which is controlling what you see in the admin menu.

Comment: which are the phpmyadmin login credentials? the same as wp-admin?

Comment: Not usually the same as your wp-admin info. You'll want to access it from your webhost level. Either inside their control panel (maybe cpanel if that's what you're using).  

If you're using a remote MySQL software, and it's enabled for remote login, then you could use the credentials in your wp-config.php for database - but usually you would access it from your web host level.

Comment: The page is hosted on Godaddy, so I must log there first and see on cpanel and there i can see wp-config.php to modify? I will request my friend for the loggin credentials of godday to see thanks you a lot

Comment: @ConorTreacy, in newer versions of WordPress (starting from version 2.0), the `wp_user_level` field is no longer used, and the user's role and permissions are stored in the `wp_capabilities` field instead. The `wp_capabilities` field is a serialized array that contains a list of the user's roles, with the keys corresponding to the roles and the values set to `true` or `false`.

Comment: @ConorTreacy ,  For example, if a user has the "administrator" role, the `wp_capabilities` field for that user might contain the following value: `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}`. This value indicates that the user has the "administrator" role, with the key `s:13:"administrator"` corresponding to the role and the value `b:1;` indicating that the `role is enabled`. My answer below explains this better

Comment: Ah, very good. Ive removed the notes in my answer. Thanks for the extra clarification. I remember those serialized arrays now, just didn't click in my head when I checked phpmyadmin and saw the wp_userdata instead. Thanks @tamara

Comment: thanks you a lot